# How do I display related fields content that is part of the children of a post

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have this model that is a reply to a post. But replies can also have replies and it can carry on forever. If I look at a reply I would like to see the user profile that made the reply. I can see the profile of the user that made the parent reply but not the profile of the user that made the child reply.

Here is the reply model

```
class Reply(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    video = models.FileField(
        upload_to=reply_videos_directory_path, null=True, blank=True
    )
    body = models.TextField(max_length=256, default=None)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        "self", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name="replies"
    )

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Created at")
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Updated at")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "post reply"
        verbose_name_plural = "post replies"
        db_table = "post_reply"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.body[0:30]
```

and here is the serializer for the reply and I can get the information I need for the parent reply but how do I pull in the profile data of a child reply? For example replies have an author and that author has a profile. I can pull in the profile for the parent reply but how do I pull the profile in for the child reply?

```
class ReplySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = ReplyImageSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, required=False)
    post = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    profile = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    post_images = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Reply
        fields = [
            "id",
            "post",
            "post_images",
            "video",
            "images",
            "body",
            "parent",
            "replies",
            "profile",
            "created_at",
            "updated_at",
        ]
        depth = 1

    def get_post(self, obj):
        post_obj = Post.objects.get(id=obj.post.id)
        post = ShortPostSerializer(post_obj)
        return post.data

    def get_profile(self, obj):
        profile_obj = Profile.objects.get(id=obj.user.profile.id)
        profile = ShortProfileSerializer(profile_obj)
        return profile.data

    def get_post_images(self, obj):
        images = PostImage.objects.filter(post=obj.post.id)
        serializer = PostImageSerializer(images, many=True)
        return serializer.data     
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        new_reply = Reply.objects.create(**validated_data)
        images = dict((self.context['request'].FILES).lists()).get('images', None)
        if images:
            for image in images:
                ReplyImage.objects.create(
                    image=image, reply=new_reply
                )
        return new_reply
```

The data returned looks like this and under replies there is a user id and I would like to pull in the profile for that user?

```
{"id":8,"post":{"body":"Post TWO by the user koos","category":{"id":1,"name":"General","slug":"general","description":"General post category","created_at":"2022-12-06T01:49:34.683671Z","updated_at":"2022-12-06T01:49:34.683693Z","parent":null},"video":null,"created_at":"2023-01-05T04:40:02.994033Z"},"post_images":[{"id":47,"image":"/storage/posts/52/images/bg3.jpg","post":52},{"id":48,"image":"/storage/posts/52/images/bg4.jpg","post":52},{"id":49,"image":"/storage/posts/52/images/bg5.jpg","post":52},{"id":50,"image":"/storage/posts/52/images/bg7.jpg","post":52}],"video":null,"images":[{"id":7,"image":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/replies/8/images/bmw-rr-3.jpg","reply":8}],"body":"Comment 1 on post 2 by user koos","parent":null,"replies":[{"id":6,"video":null,"body":"comment 1 on comment 1 on post 2 by user koos","created_at":"2023-01-05T04:45:06.846403Z","updated_at":"2023-01-07T09:23:54.986186Z","user":1,"post":52,"parent":8},{"id":21,"video":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/1/posts/52/replies/8/videos/WhatsApp_Video_2020-10-09_at_10.22.36.mp4","body":"Comment 2 on comment 1 of post 2 by user koos","created_at":"2023-01-07T10:46:14.134659Z","updated_at":"2023-01-07T10:46:14.134696Z","user":1,"post":52,"parent":8}],"profile":{"photo":"/storage/profiles/images/1/tumblr_88af0e2145b389cc684a7c343fa9980a_d96ebf87_1280_p2cSfII.jpg","first_name":"Calvin","middle_name":"","last_name":"Cani","user":{"id":1,"username":"koos","role":"EM","email":"cal@calvincani.com","is_staff":true,"is_superuser":true,"is_advertiser":false}},"created_at":"2023-01-05T04:47:30.017931Z","updated_at":"2023-01-07T09:17:58.476112Z"}
```

Also if I pull in the profile for the user in the reply serializer in any case why am I not seeing it for the child replies?

I see that the fields in the child replies match that of the model. so what serializes those fields?

Is there another way to approach this and should I do it differently? This seems to be quite hard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this would work but have you tried declaring the field with its own serializer?

```
replies = ReplySerializer(many=True, read_only=True, required=False)
```

Comment: A question if I may how do I deal with RelatedObjectDoesNotExist in case someone does not have a profile yet?

Comment: I think that in the `get_profile` method you have to see if the profile exists and avoid returning a `None` object. 
You can try `profile_obj = Profile.objects.filter(id=obj.user.profile.id).first()`. `profile_obj` will be `None` if the filter doesn't find any match. Then you can do `if profile_obj: execute logic`